# Simple string.replace() is failing for javascript in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript

I have microsoft edge version 40, it is really old but I can't update my Edge without updating my W10 OS, and thats like 4 gigs or something and I don't have the SSD space to spare. Plus there are reports this is happening on the newer versions too.

Anyway here is the following code that causes the error:

```
varvalue = varvalue.replace("'", '');
varvalue = varvalue.replace('"', '');
```

And when I'm on edge I get this error in the console works in all other browsers including IE:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'
```

When I comment out the code causing the error, it goes away and everything is fine, so I KNOW that it is these lines causing the issue. Only for Microsoft Edge though.

Basically I'm checking if varvalue contains either an apostrophe or double apostrophe (which it usually will for whatever reason) then it needs to be stripped out of the string, so I'm just looking for any of those in the string and removing them.

Comment: The error is telling you that as much as you believed `varvalue` to be a string, it isn't, because whatever it is, is doesn't have a `.replace` property, which strings definitely do. So: what is it? A simple `console.log({ varvalue })` before your replaces should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Edge does not think `varvalue` is a string, but rather an object.

This is probably caused by the method in which it receives the data, and not these replace functions.

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for wasting yalls time, sometimes varvalue gets set to an integer and Edge doesn't like that.

Comment: then you probably want to delete your question again, since you basically figured it out on your own.

Comment: I've heard you can get your posting ability blocked for deleting posts / comments.